# Можно поставить запятую перед одиночным союзом ИЛИ между однородными членами?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены, или

*– Я не струсила. **Но вдруг кто-то тяжело заболеет, или будет ранен?** Обратится ко мне за помощью, за спасением, а что я? Самозванцем может быть кто угодно, но только не врач!*
Из книги Б. Акунина.

**Вместо вступления**

1. У автора стоит запятая перед союзом  ИЛИ. Ошибка? Ведь существует [правило Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=100#pp100):

**Пункт 4.** Перед неповторяющимися разделительными союзами ***или, либо*** между однородными членами предложения запятая **не ставится**: *Цветы лучше всего собирать **утром или под вечер*** (Пауст.); …***Приеду** по весне к вам **либо отправлюсь** на Кавказ* (Бат.).

Но правила Розенталя – это **базовый вариант**, в литературе достаточно ситуаций, которые нельзя объяснить правилами.

2. В данном случае оба варианта (с запятой и без запятой)  **кажутся возможными:** (1) *Но вдруг кто-то тяжело заболеет или будет ранен?* (2) *Но вдруг кто-то тяжело заболеет, или будет ранен?*

Сравним с другим предложением: *Купи блокнот или тетрадь. Собрание состоится в пятницу или в субботу.* Эти предложения выглядят одновариантными.

3. **Союз ИЛИ  разделительный**,  это логическая дизъюнкция (от лат. disjunctio — разобщение, обособление). В грамматике обозначает альтернативность или выбор.  Но при отсутствии запятой и перечислительной интонации он как бы «соединяет» однородные члены. И вот в одном случае такое  «соединение» выглядит как **единственно верное**, а в другом **возможны варианты**. Почему?

**Вопрос**

Можно ли считать постановку запятой **допустимой и почему** автор ставит запятую: *Но вдруг кто-то тяжело заболеет, или будет ранен?*

**Спасибо** (за то, что прочитали вопрос, и за ваш ответ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запятую можно объяснить только присоединительным характером второго однородного члена. Это допустимо, если автор хочет показать паузу в речи своего персонажа, расставить акценты:

*Но вдруг кто-то тяжело заболЕет, или будет рАнен?* – два ударения.
*Но вдруг кто-то тяжело заболеет или будет рАнен?* – основное ударение в самом конце предложения (вопросительная интонация также может способствовать объединению в одно целое, как в случае сложносочинённого предложения).

Интересная цитата приведена в этом учебнике:
Валгина Н. С., Розенталь Д. Э., Фомина М. И. Современный русский язык
([**Присоединительные конструкции**](https://topuch.com/udk-811-161-1-bbk-81-2rus-92-3-v-15/index52.html)).

> Существенная особенность присоединительных конструкций вскрыта Л.В. Щербой: «при присоединении 'второй' элемент появляется в сознании лишь после первого или во время его высказывания», в отличие от сочинения, при котором «оба члена присутствуют в сознании, хотя бы в смутном виде, уже при самом начале высказывания».
> <...>
> Характерная особенность присоединительных конструкций – разрыв между ними и основным высказыванием. Поэтому они стоят после длительной паузы и выделяются логически и интонационно.
> <...>
> На письме степень длительности паузы передается разными знаками препинания.
> При союзном присоединении обычно употребляется запятая.

Так что запятую поставить можно, и это не ошибка. А для "большей ясности" (и чтобы не возникало вопросов у тех, кто знает о ненужности запятой перед неповторяющимся союзом ***или*** и пока не допускает возможности его присоединительного значения в подобных структурах) лучше, на мой взгляд, выбрать другой знак:

*Но вдруг кто-то тяжело заболеет... или будет ранен?

Но вдруг кто-то тяжело заболеет? Или будет ранен?*

> При союзном присоединении возможна также постановка многоточия в том случае, если необходимо передать некоторую незавершенность основного высказывания и, кроме того, паузу большой длительности.
> <...>
> Чаще, однако, постановка точки.
> <...>
> Союз *или: Выбросьте процесс. Или роман. В конце концов, что важнее?* (Н. И.).

И ещё:

> Широкое употребление присоединительных конструкций в современной художественной литературе – свидетельство сближения письменного литературного языка с разговорным.

Comment: Комментарий пришлось оформить в виде ответа.  Вот только большие тексты, где много буковок, никто не читает))

Comment: Александр, соглашусь с Sharon, здесь нет присоединительной интонации.

Comment: @Серж  А какую интонацию будет выражать запятая? Перечислительную? Очень тонкая грань, которую, как мне кажется, здесь не найти.

Comment: Александр, в русском языке интонационный принцип пунктуации находится на третьем месте. Поэтому не всегда там, где есть пауза, ставится запятая. И наоборот. Там, где нет паузы, ставится пауза. В приведенном примере я бы не стал ставить запятую.

Comment: @Серж Это всё понятно. Но если нет присоединительной интонации, то какая она в свете того, что Sharon **за** постановку запятой? Вопрос, наверно, больше к вам, Sharon.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец, так я о том же пишу. Запятая не ставится вопреки интонации.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец  Да, паузу с помощью запятой не отрегулировать (здесь возможности  не безграничны, не все тонкости произношения можно обозначить знаками).  Но если мы обратимся к грамматике, то пауза между однородными членами все-таки отличается от подчеркнутой паузы для присоединительных членов, которая чаще обозначается тире, а не запятой.

Answer (score 4):

**Комментарий**

**Спасибо, Александр,** за ваш ответ, как всегда интересный и развернутый  (и еще много за что, всего и не перечислишь).

**О семантике и интонации**

**С ударением** я полностью  согласна, я даже думаю, что у Акунина это **основная причина** для постановки запятой. Ему важно было сделать сказуемые **равноправными**, иначе ударение действительно уходит в конец предложения и ставится только на второе сказуемое.

**Присоединительная конструкция?** Да, такой вариант тоже возможен, но там предполагается грамматическая **пауза**, в то время как автору, как мне думается, достаточно только правильной расстановки ударений.

Да и по содержанию **присоединение менее вероятно.** Там девушка переодевается в мужскую одежду под видом ученика лекаря,  чтобы попасть на корабль, и она заранее знает о возможных ранах, опасаясь их в первую очередь (корабль корсарский). Она даже собиралась запретить капитану нападать на другие корабли.

В то же время такое объяснение дает возможность **не нарушать правила** (универсальный прием).

**О грамматике**

**Теперь о самом правиле**, которое однозначно запрещает ставить запятую в случае одиночного союза ИЛИ.  А почему, ведь союз **разделительный** и при объединении однородных членов в одну фразу мы имеем «неразделенную дизъюнкцию».  Да, она  в языке допускается, но **почему так должно быть всегда?**

В одних случаях (возможно, их большинство) это действительно нужно, а в других автор должен иметь возможность **выбора,** как в данном тексте.

Кстати, об **«общем элементе»** для однородных членов, в частности о вопросительной интонации.  (Это предложение можно переделать в повествовательное, а запятая все рано будет нужна.)  Но возможно, необходимость **объединения** однородных членов при отсутствии запятой как-то связана с таким «общим элементом».
*Купи блокнот или тетрадь* **(что-нибудь).** *Собрание состоится в пятницу или в субботу* (**на этой неделе**). Здесь союз ИЛИ объединяет **второстепенные члены**, а у нас сказуемые. Может быть,  вариант со сказуемыми нуждается в большей **свободе действий** (такая вот философия).

**Вывод**

Мне хотелось бы, чтобы автор получил **законное право на постановку запятой** и  не оправдывался перед читателями по поводу ее **присутствия.** А то, к примеру, наш oleedd, когда речь идет об авторских знаках, считает, что я оправдываю виновных в совершении ошибок.

Другими словами, надо бы дополнить правило Розенталя хотя бы **примечанием** о возможности такой запятой (немножко "реформировать").

Вот с таким предложением **вы согласились бы или нет?**

Comment: Конечно согласился бы. И действительно, автору не нужно оправдываться, ведь постановка запятой может диктоваться интонацией (пусть даже не предполагалось присоединение). Это они, въедливые читатели, должны понять замысел, вникнуть в поток и разобраться в тонкостях записи, передающей устную речь.

Comment: Спасибо, завтра приму ваш ответ, а то вдруг кто-нибудь еще на вопрос ответит. А на уже принятые ответы никто не отвечает.

Comment: *Вот только большие тексты, где много буковок, никто не читает.* Читаем, Sharon, — еще как читаем! И на принятые ответы периодически отвечаем. Чего ж Вы всех-то — одной гребенкой? P. S. Спасибо за вопрос и комментарий. Будоражьте нас почаще — Вас не хватает на форуме. P. P. S. И внимательно читаем... *...не оправдывался перед читателями по поводу ее отсутствия.* Мне кажется, что надо *её **присутствия***. Не?

Comment: Ну, стрижка под одну гребенку — это риторический прием для вдохновения участников. Я знаю, кто читает длинные тексты, кто приходит сюда за знаниями, и вы уж точно читаете. И спасибо за замечание, сейчас поправлю. Вы (и Александр тоже) удивительно внимательны, а для меня это недостижимый идеал. Я, конечно, стараюсь, но не всегда получается. Времени мало, но все-таки буду заходить на форум. Здесь для меня особая энергетика: манит к себе, притягивает…